# WIN32: Is there a way to have the button icon (BM_SETIMAGE) on the right side of the text

Tags: winapi, comctl32

Is there a way to have a button with text and graphic, with the graphic on the right side of the text, without having to owner-draw the button?

I want to just sent `BM_SETIMAGE` and whatever else would be needed so the graphic is to the right of the text.

Also, I noticed the image is so tight against the text that it doesn't look good. Is there a way to adjust the margin without having to use a blank space in the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to have a button with text and graphic, with the graphic on the right side of the text, without having to owner-draw the button?

There are `BS_LEFTTEXT` and `BS_RIGHTBUTTON` styles available, but the documentation says they only apply to CheckBoxes and RadioButtons:

> | Constant | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | BS_LEFTTEXT | Places text on the left side of the radio button or check box when combined with a radio button or check box style. Same as the BS_RIGHTBUTTON style. |
> | BS_RIGHTBUTTON | Positions a radio button's circle or a check box's square on the right side of the button rectangle. Same as the BS_LEFTTEXT style. |

For a standard push button, there does not appear to be a way to control the position of the image other than through owner-drawing.

> Is there a way to adjust the margin without having to use a blank space in the text?

Use [`BCM_SETTEXTMARGIN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bcm-settextmargin)/[`Button_SetTextMargin()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-button_settextmargin):

> Sets the margins for drawing text in a button control.